# Python error can't find PyQt.Qtcore, when launching QGIS

Tags: qgis

I installed QGIS in Linux and it was working fine. I try to launch the program again and I get the following Python error:

```
Couldn't load plugin MetaSearch due to an error when calling its classFactory() method


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/natalia/.qgis2/python/plugins/MetaSearch/__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
    from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/natalia/.qgis2/python/plugins/MetaSearch/plugin.py", line 28, in 
    from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named PyQt.QtCore
```

However, I do have installed PyQt.QtCore. I think the problem is with my path and QGIS doesn't know how to look for the Python package.

I am really new to this, I am not sure how to fix it.  The way that my path looks is:

```
PATH=/home/usr/.qgis2/python:$PATH
PATH=/home/usr/share/qgis/python:$PATH
```

Comment: Yo may try to follow the steps in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/237859/87487) answer.