# How to get an equivalent to stand-alone installation of QGIS using OSGEO4W?

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis, osgeo4w

What should be downloaded / set (beyond the obvious) when installing QGIS using the OSGEO4W package manager - in order to end up with an equivalent setup to that which would result from using the QGIS standalone installer?

Documentation and advice make the basics clear in terms of [installing one or more versions of QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) but aren't so clear on what else is required should a full equivalent install be desired.

The requirements are different when using 'Express Install' and 'Advanced' options in the installer. The notes below relate to the use of the 'advanced' option.

At least the following three things seem to be required:

- <del>Select 'qt4-devel' in the OSGEO4W installer so that you have access to QT Designer</del> [EDIT: I think I'm wrong on this one... qt4-devel ought to be downloaded automatically as part of a QGIS installation]
- Set the [GDAL environment variable](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable)
- Select 'grass: GRASS GIS - stable release' in the OSGEO4W installer.
- Select 'saga-ltr: SAGA (System for Automated ...' in the OSGEO4W installer.

What else is necessary? Are these correct?

This question was prompted because 've been sent a processing script which works fine on QGIS on machines where this has been installed using the standalone installer. When I try to run it on my machine (given that I installed QGIS using the OSGEO4W installer) it gives an error. It can't find the python module "PYQT4.QtCore" and I suspect that this is because I didn't fully know what I was doing when installing QGIS using the installer. I don't know how to fix this. I don't understand what further settings (etc) are required. You might think that someone with my level of knowledge should stick to installing QGIS with the stand alone installer, but I'm working in an organisation where we're trying to manage about 40 QGIS installations, sticking to the LTR version of QGIS for all users and the move from the stand alone installer seems important.

Comment: Why not uninstall, then try Express Desktop Install? That seems to deliver the same product as the standalone in my experience. You could do that, then open the OSGeo4W Shell and type setup to open the installer again, then go to Advanced install and see which packages were installed as a result of selecting the Express Desktop option. qt4-devel and qt4-libs and qwt-5-libs-qt4 appear to be included. Among many others.

Comment: For the PYQT4.QtCore issue, you might compare the python paths between the installations, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238596/python-error-cant-find-pyqt-qtcore-when-launching-qgis and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632169/qgis-pyqt4-missing-qstring-class. But I think this is worth a new question.

Comment: Have followed she_weeds idea on a separate machine as part of my problem solving process - creating a list of what's installed and what not. The additions of GRASS and SAGA to the list above are from this work. You're right that pyqt4 is included. It seems to me that I'm getting different results using the installer on different machines depending on what was previously installed - because on my work machine, having now installed GRASS/SAGA using the installer now I still can't get the processing scripts to run. No idea why. Next step will be an uninstall-reinstall on this machine.