# How to download the full OSGeoW64 installer for a previous version of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2.18

I need to install the full OSGeo4W64 version for 2.18.6, Windows 10, 64-bit.  However, the previous release page only has the standalone QGIS installer:

http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.18.6-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

Where do I find the full OSGeoW64 installer for 2.18.6?

=========================================

Edit:

After following the answer from @mgri below, I get the following error when I try to run 2.18.6:

[image]

However, qgis_app.dll does exist, in the correct path.

I have reinstalled twice, each time using the latest full OSGeoW64 installer (which is the only installer I am aware of, and installs 2.18.7 by default).  The first time I followed mgri's instructions at the initial install, requesting 2.18.6.  The error ensued.  The second time I installed 2.18.7, then went back and did a custom install, again following mgri's instructions, and modified the install to revert to 2.18.6.  Again, the error.

After an [internet search](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/exe-entry-point-not-found/5b0866c1-8e45-457e-a83c-651c1fd307cc) regarding "Entry Point Not Found", I ran the [Windows System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files), but it turned up no problems.

I am still unable to install 2.18.6, looking for assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the standalone install works for you, and OSGEO4W64 at least installs QGIS and the GDAL FileGDB driver, you can add FileGDB support to the standalone version by copying the files

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_FileGDB.dll
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\FileGDBAPI.dll
```

to the folders used by the standalone version, i.e.

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalplugins\
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\
```

Both GDAL installations are version 2.1.3 in my case.

Comment: Perfect!  That solved the problem.  I also restarted the computer; I don't know if that was required.  In retrospect, I should have mentioned that I needed the FGDB support in my OP, my apologies.  If you would like to post as an answer, I will give you credit.  Thanks also to @mgri.

Answer (score 4):

You may downgrade to the previous version by directly using the OSGeo4W Setup:

[image]

In the above image, on the left there is the currently installed version and, on the right, the previous version will be shown if you click two times on the *Skip* selector that will appear.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Your answer made perfect sense.  I followed your instructions, and the install proceeded without error.  However, when I tried to start 2.18.6, an error message appeared.  I saved a screenshot, but I don't know how to insert a picture in this comment.  The error was titled "Entry point not found", and it referred to C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\bin\qgis_app.dll.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @StuSmith I can edit your original question for adding more information about the issue. However, you may try to restart the system, or even to delete the `.qgis2` folder (follow the suggestion in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/237859/87487) post).

Comment: Does it help if you install into a different folder?

Comment: @StuSmith What about the suggestion by @AndreJ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem exists with the answer from @AndreJ

Comment: Do you run into the same error with one of the standalone versions from http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/ ?

Comment: No, the standalone install does not have this error.  However, I need the full install so that I can customize to allow read/write of ESRI FGDB.