# Difference between QGIS download and OSGeoW4 Network installer

Tags: qgis-3, installation, osgeo4w

I'm setting up my new computer and I want to reinstall QGIS. In the past, whenever a new version of QGIS was released, I downloaded the MSI file from the QGIS website.

Once the installer was run, it would install the new version as if it was the first installation of the software. I would eventually end up with 4 or 5 versions on my system concurrently, each taking up 2-3 GB of hard drive space.

If I used the OSGeo4W installer, will the same problem occur whenever a new QGIS version is released, or will the network installer only install the updates?

Comment: This link will help you (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/189076/143290).

Comment: Thanks. That link seems to be what I was looking for. Unfortunately, the NextGIS option that is mentioned in that thread is subscription based and I'm not paying for yet another subscription at this point in time.

Answer (score 4):

The OSGeo4W installer shows what QGIS versions can be installed. It is possible to install different versions of QGIS with the installer

- QGIS desktop (latest release)
- QGIS-dev (nightly build)
- QGIS long term release

[image]

Each of these versions can be installed and upgraded independently.
For your needs I would recommend to install only the latest released version or the LTR version with the OSGeo4W installer. When you want to upgrade just run the installer again. It will update all the required packages but it will not install another copy of QGIS on your computer.